# Find and update column 3

Tags: awk, sed

First file

```
ireuatsypmaz_001       2203   001400222BF40001
ireuatsypmaz_002       2203   001400222BF40002
ireuatsypmaz_003       2203   001400222BF4000A
ireuatsypmaz_004       2203   001400222BF40009
ireuatsypmaz_001       2203   001400222BF40009
```

2nd file

```
ireuatsypmaz_003    server1
ireuatsypmaz_003    server2
ireuatsypmaz_003    server3

#> grep ireuatsypmaz_003 first_file
ireuatsypmaz_003       2203   001400222BF4000A
```

How can i make this pattern without using for loop?

```
ireuatsypmaz_003    server1     001400222BF4000A
ireuatsypmaz_003    server2     001400222BF4000A
ireuatsypmaz_003    server3     001400222BF4000A
```

by the way 2nd file is dynamic so it could be 3, 4 lines and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {map[$1] = $3; next} $1 in map {print $0, map[$1]}' f1 f2
```

```
ireuatsypmaz_003    server1 001400222BF4000A
ireuatsypmaz_003    server2 001400222BF4000A
ireuatsypmaz_003    server3 001400222BF4000A
```

**Details:**

```
FNR == NR {             # While processing the first file
  map[$1] = $3          # store the 3rd field by the 1st in a map
  next
}
$1 in map {             # While processing the second file, if $1 is found in map
   print $0, map[$1]    # print full record and value from map
}
```